# Can't install local python package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools

After few system upgrades I am no more able to install my Python 3 package. This is the output:

```
    pab@pab:~/Mopiqtt-1.0.0 $ sudo pip3 install .
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Processing /home/pab/Mopiqtt-1.0.0
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/home/pab/Mopiqtt-1.0.0/setup.py", line 46, in <module>
          'mqtt = mopiqtt:Extension',
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 86, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 75, in _install_setup_requires
          dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 57, in __init__
          super().__init__(filtered)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 475, in __init__
          for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 999, in entry_points
          return SelectableGroups.load(eps).select(**params)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 449, in load
          ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 997, in <genexpr>
          dist.entry_points for dist in unique(distributions())
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/_itertools.py", line 16, in unique_everseen
          k = key(element)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 931, in _normalized_name
          return self._name_from_stem(stem) or super()._normalized_name
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 600, in _normalized_name
          return Prepared.normalize(self.name)
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/_vendor/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 855, in normalize
          return re.sub(r"[-_.]+", "-", name).lower().replace('-', '_')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
          return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
      TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am struggling with this and can't find a solution. Relevant packages versions:

```
pip                    22.1.1
setuptools             62.3.2
ez-setup               0.9
```

Thanks for any help.

[Edit}: Same problem if I run `python3 setup.py check`

Comment: This is my setup.py:  https://gist.github.com/fmarzocca/6f60ad4684a286df5679dcb652b20ecf

Comment: Please include a minified version of your `setup.py` in the post. Have you tried using `python -m pip install .`? Running `pip` with `sudo` is almost always not the thing you want to do.

Comment: setup.py is here: https://gist.github.com/fmarzocca/6f60ad4684a286df5679dcb652b20ecf    The problem is the same if I run python3 setup.py check

Comment: I've seen the link. Your question is not self-contained. It is impossible to answer it without going to another website. You would've easily done yourself and others a solid if you minified the code in question, then posted it here to get an answer about the _actual_ mechanism behind the issue.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik, it is always github and I don't see the point to click on a link. Anyway, thanks for kind cooperation.

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18670/309533

Comment: ok, you took 3 messages for this and despite you having read my file, you didn't help a word for my problem but only raised a "procedural" issue. As I said, thank you very much for your cooperation.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being your personal free debugging service. It is expected here, that you give at least a modicum of your own time to get someone else's back. You refuse to give yours by not minifying your code and adding it into the post. This leaves the post impossible to benefit from for people other than you, that's why I'm reluctant to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this by downgrading setuptools:

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall setuptools==40.8.0
```

but I don't have any idea of the bug....